# Updating jint variable in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

When below JNI function is called dataByteArray (of jbyteArray type) is correctly received by the Application (Android/java) calling the function. But sizeDataByteArray (of jint type) is not received by the application. Please let me know what is wrong in below code.

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_helloworld_Tester_getData
(JNIEnv* env, jclass clasz, jbyteArray dataByteArray, jint sizeDataByteArray) {

    // Some code 
    l_data = “01:02:03:AB:CD:EF”;
    l_data_size = strlen(l_data);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(dataByteArray, 0, strlen(l_data), (jbyte *) l_data);
    sizeDataByteArray = l_data_size;

    // Some code
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Suppose I wrote a Java function: `public void getData(byte[] dataByteArray, int sizeDataByteArray) {System.arraycopy(l_data, 0, dataByteArray, 0, l_data_size); sizeDataByteArray = l_data_size;}`. Why the dataByteArray (of byte[] type) is correctly received but the sizeDataByteAray (of int type) is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create class for return multiple values from native code:

```
public class ReturnValue {
    public final boolean success;
    public final byte[] result;

    public ReturnValue(boolean success, byte[] result) {
        this.success = success;
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

return this object from jni you can implement this way:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_helloworld_Tester_getData
          (JNIEnv* env, jclass clasz, jbyteArray dataByteArray, jint sizeDataByteArray) {
    const char* cls_name = "com/example/helloworld/ReturnValue";
    // try to obtain ReturnValue class
    jclass cls = env->FindClass(cls_name);
    // if exception occurred return control to java 
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred())
        return NULL;

    const char* constructor_signature = "(Z[B)V";
    // try to obtain ReturnValue constructor
    jmethodID constructorId = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", constructor_signature);
    // if exception occurred return control to java 
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred())
            return NULL;

    jboolean success = true;
    jbyteArray data = env->NewByteArray(0);

    // fill data array...

    // create ReturnValue object. If exception occurred, 
    // control will be returned java automatically in this case
    return env->NewObject(cls, constructorId, success, data);
}
```

Read additional information about jni method calling and method's signatures in [this article](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass two arrays

- array for bytes
- array for ints

First array will contain string you want to pass back.

Second array, will contain only one element - length of the string.

Take a look here to see how to commit changes and pass them back to Java.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-013/

In your case, you will pass something like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_recipeNo013_PassArrayBack_passIntArray
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jbyteArray dataByteArray, jintArray sizeArray) {

  // Here you are doing all the things with your dataByteArray

  /* get size of the array - it should be 1, as you want just one elem*/
  jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, sizeArray);

  /* get the body of array; it will be referecende by C pointer */
  jint *body = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, array, 0);

  /* do some stuff */
  body[0] = l_data_size;

  (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, sizeArray, body, JNI_COMMIT);

  return true;
}
```

This way, you can return both: array of bytes and it's size

Comment: In your example we need to create data and sizes arrays appropriate length in java (before jni call), but at this stage we can't understand how many elements jni method will return

Comment: We don't have to know that in advance (the size of array). "sizeArray" is one element array. It contains only one value -  size of the byte array created inside JNI code.

Comment: You can to return data size this way - it will work. How you suggest to return data from jni?

Comment: I guess you mention the first array - dataByteArray. This is true. Here, the size must be fixed as well (allocated in Java). However, author mentioned that this is not a problem for him: "When below JNI function is called dataByteArray (of jbyteArray type) is correctly received by the Application (Android/java) calling the function.". So, I assume he passes buffer with enough free space to fill the data. The initial issue was how to pass another value by - let's call it - "reference".

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeDataByteArray` parameter is passed by value, so the modification you made in the function is not reflected to the caller side.

You may return the data length instead of returning a boolean value.

Also you need to be sure that `dataByteArray` has enough space to store passed data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cannot return the data length as I also need the boolean value. Is there a way to update sizeDataByteArray variable within the function & pass back. (like pass by reference method)